# How to handle language specific subdomains in express?

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization

Using nodejs and express, I try to set the language based on a "subfolder" in the routes. This language parameter is optional. Is there a way of doing this without having to change all the routes to contain the optional language parameter?

For example, I want 
mydomain.tld/mypath/  and mydomain.tld/de/mypath/ to trigger the same route for /mypath/ , with a middleware which detects the /de/ (if present) and sets locale variables accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to resort to checking for the special case of there being a language tag in the route, and then rewriting `req.url` in the middleware, setting the correct locale variables. Here is a simple sketch example of how this could be done.

```
var languages = ["de", ...];

function routeLanguage(req, res, next) {
  var lang, parts = req.path.split("/");
  if (parts[1] && (lang = languages[parts[1]])) {
    req.url = req.url.replace(/^\/[^/]*/, "");
    // set locale vars using lang
  }
  return next();
}
```

This middleware will reroute any "language path" to the normal route (`/de/mypath` goes to `/mypath`).

Be careful, as this will not work for the default language if you have a language tag as a path, i.e. `/de` will route to `/` with `de` as language and `/de/de` will route to `/de`.

**Update:**

This simplifies somewhat if you assume a mount point for the middleware, as express can then use it's regex parsing on the path. You could also defer the localization logic to later in the stack, by assigning the parsed language to for example `req.lang`.

```
app.use(/^\/(de|en|...)\//, function (req, res, next) {
  req.lang = req.params[0];
  req.url = req.url.replace(/^\/[^/]*/, "");
  next();
});
```

Comment: Hmm. Is this the only way? Using express.Router,  it's already possible to "digest" a part of the URL, for instance: router.use('/api', require('./api')); , and then in "api.js" defining a route like "/test", which would handle everything routed to /api/test.

Comment: See my updated solution using explicit routes. Although you still need to rewrite the url for the remaining middleware/routes.